# Sql consulta de filtros

Tags: sql

En la siguiente consulta , el usuario tiene varias opciones de filtrado, puede filtrar por nombre,cargo,area,sede el problema es **que el campo nombre no esta filtrando**, no esta retornando nada en cambio con los demas filtros si retorna resultados

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$cargo=$_POST['cargo'];
$area=$_POST['area'];
$sede=$_POST['sede'];

$registro=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT
                                  nombre,
                                  apellidos,
                                  cargo,
                                  area,
                                  correocorporativo,
                                  extension 
                                  FROM  formulario
                                  WHERE estado='A' 
                                  AND   nombre
                                  LIKE  '%".$nombre."%'
                                  AND   area LIKE '%".$area."%'
                                  OR    cargo LIKE '%".$cargo."%'
                                  OR    sede LIKE '%".$sede."%'"
```

Comment: Sin ver los datos dificil ayudarte, por lo menos en el codigo se ve todo bien.

Comment: es correcto, debes revisar los AND y OR , de preferencia ir agregando de 1 en 1 para ver qué aportan cada uno y así ver mejor y uno está deteniendo al otro.

Answer (score 0):

Parece cosa de los AND y los OR. Vigila los paréntesis para que filtre según las necesidades. No estoy seguro de lo que necesitas exactamente pero me refiero a algo como esto:

```
WHERE estado='A' 
AND   nombre
LIKE  '%".$nombre."%'
AND   (area LIKE '%".$area."%'
OR    cargo LIKE '%".$cargo."%'
OR    sede LIKE '%".$sede."%'")
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.